# How can I uppercase the first letter of all words in my string?

Tags: c#, regex

First, all my cities were returned as UPPERCASE, so I switched them to lowercase. How can I get the first letter as uppercase now? Thanks for any help!

```
List<string> cities = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    cities.Add(row[0].ToString().ToLower());

    **ADDED THIS BUT NOTHING HAPPENED**
     CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(row[0] as string);
}

return cities;
```

Comment: added regex tag so question can be found by RegEx experts (not me) ;-)

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831/how-do-i-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-name-and-last-name-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex may seem a bit long, but works

```
List<string> cities = new List<string>();

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string city = row[0].ToString();
    cities.Add(String.Concat(Regex.Replace(city, "([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]+)", "$1").ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Regex.Replace(city, "([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]+)", "$2").ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));

}

return cities;
```

Answer (score 19):

Use the [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) method:

```
System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase();
```

A bit from the MSDN example, modified to work with OP's code:

```
// Defines the string with mixed casing.
string myString = row[0] as String;

// Creates a TextInfo based on the "en-US" culture.
TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;

// Retrieve a titlecase'd version of the string.
string myCity = myTI.ToTitleCase(myString);
```

All in one line:

```
string myCity = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(row[0] as String);
```

Comment: I saw that, but couldn't figure out how to add it to my code.

Comment: @TCC System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(row[0] as string);

Comment: @TCC click the reference to the method at MSDN. It has sample code of how to use it. I'll add some to my post to save readers some time as well.

Comment: @TCC The provided [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) gives great examples.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm resurrecting a ghost here, but I had the same problem, and wanted to share what I think is the best solution. There are a few ways you can do it, either splitting the string and replacing the first letter, or transforming it into a char-array for better performance. The best performance, though, comes with using a regular expression.

You can use a bit of [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) voodoo to find the first letter of each word. The pattern you are looking for is **\b\w** (**\b** means the beginning of a word, and **\w** is an alpha character). Use a [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx) delegate (or an equivalent lambda expression) to modify the string (the first character, that your pattern found).

Here's an extension method over string that will upper-case-ify the first letter of each word in a string:

```
static string UpperCaseFirst(this string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\b\w", (Match match)=> match.ToString().ToUpper())
}
```

Comment: It will not lowercase the non-first-letters though.

Comment: Then just apply the function to input.ToLower()

Comment: The advantage of this post against others is that there have been thoughts about the conversion performance, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an extension method that you can use. It supports the current culture, or allows you to pass in the culture.

to use:

`cities.Add(row[0].ToString().ToTitleCase()`

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use the current thread's culture info for conversion
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
    {
        var cultureInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        return cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overload which uses the culture info with the specified name
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str, string cultureInfoName)
    {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureInfoName);
        return cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overload which uses the specified culture info
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        return cultureInfo.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With linq:

```
String newString = new String(str.Select((ch, index) => (index == 0) ? ch : Char.ToLower(ch)).ToArray()); *
```

- gently stolen from this post : [How to lowercase a string except for first character with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427483/how-to-lowercase-a-string-except-for-first-character-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/uppercase-first-letter) method (or create an extension method out of it):

```
static string UpperCaseFirst(this string s)
{
    // Check for empty string.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    // Return char and concat substring.
    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's quick little method:

```
public string UpperCaseFirstLetter(string YourLowerCaseWord)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(YourLowerCaseWord))
        return string.Empty;

    return char.ToUpper(YourLowerCaseWord[0]) + YourLowerCaseWord.Substring(1);
}
```

Comment: What if i send in `string.Empty`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string UppercaseFirst(string value)
    {
        // Check for empty string.
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        // Return char and concat substring.
        return char.ToUpper(value[0]) + value.Substring(1);
    }
```

cities.Select(UppercaseFirst).ToList();